# DDS Openslice: How to create a listener in python

Tags: python, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I am using ADLINK's OpenSplice and their Python API.  I cannot seem to find good documentation or a class reference.  I'd like to setup a non-blocking way to receive multiple messages.  Their Listener seems to provide this but it is not clear how to set it up in python.

Their DDS tutorial gives a C example:

```
class TempSensorListener :
   public dds::sub::NoOpDataReaderListener<tutorial::TempSensorType>
   {
      public:
      virtual void on_data_available(dds::sub::DataReader<tutorial::TempSensorType>& dr)
      {
         ...
      });
   }
};

TempSensorListener listener;
dr.listener(&listener, dds::core::status::StatusMask::data_available());
```

This seems to indicate that the datareceiver has a "listener" method used to assign a listener to the datareader.

How is this done using the Python API?  I cannot seem to find the listener method from the python datareceiver.

The provided Python examples (example1.py and example2.py) provide

```
# Data available listener
class DataAvailableListener(Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        Listener.__init__(self)

    def on_data_available(self, entity):
        print('on_data_available called')
        l = entity.read(10)
        for (sd, si) in l:
            sd.print_vars()
```

But I see no instantiation of the class.  The example seems to use Waitset and not use the listener at all

I expected something like:

```
listener = DataAvailableListener()
reader.listener(listener)
```

reader does have an attribute called listener.  I assigning the object to that attribute but it didnt seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I found a solution to the same problem as of 6.10.4:

Referring to the docs from the `dds` package (included in your `$OSPL_HOME/tools/python/docs/html/dds.html`) you can setup a listener using the `create_datareader` method of the `Subscriber` class:

> ```
> from dds import *
> from foo import foo_type # idlpp generated module/class
>
> # Data available listener
> class DataAvailableListener(Listener):
>     def __init__(self):
>         Listener.__init__(self)
>
>     def on_data_available(self, entity):
>         print('on_data_available called')
>         l = entity.read(10)
>         for (sd, si) in l:
>             sd.print_vars()
>
> dp = DomainParticipant()
> topic = dp.create_topic('foo_topic',foo_type)
> sub = dp.create_subscriber()
> sub.create_datareader(topic,listener=DataAvailableListener())
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I looked thru the code in github and found that.  I was going to post back but I found that it drops messages when I send them too fast even though the C implementation works fine.